# Masyu turned vanilla

Tags: grid-deduction, masyu

Tried to make something clever, but it didn't work out so you're getting a vanilla masyu instead.

Normal [masyu rules](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu.html) apply.

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go:

> [image]

Anyone can use [this](https://puzz.link/p?mashu/10/10/0016b0000i000ii102013010i20ic00030) for the playing board.